# Why does my favicon revert to a server icon when I call "View Source"?

Tags: html, favicon, view-source

This [website](http://www.pathfolios.com) has a favicon:

```
link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.pathfolios.com/sites/default/files/Untitled-1%20copy%20%281%29.png" type="image/png"
```

The favicon appears normally when accessing pages within the site.

When using admin pages and particularly "viewing source" the icon becomes a stock icon of the server host. It happens on other computers as well.

Is it as simple as putting my icon file as favicon.ico?

I really want to know why if possible.

Comment: You should probably be using .ico

Comment: "Is it as simple as putting my icon file as favicon.ico?" Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to covert it http://www.convertico.com/